# Displaying correct image in modal when clicking on it using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making slider with Angularjs using modal. I'm trying to accomplish when clicking on picture modal pops up displaying image that I have clicked.

.html

```
<div class="float" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">

                <div class="column is-narrow topIcons">
                    <div class="photo topIconsHover" ng-click="$ctrl.togglePicture()">
                        <figure class="image is-128x128">
                            <img ng-src="{{a.imageSrc}}">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-background" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f"></div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <p class="image is-4by3">
                        <img ng-src="{{togglePicture(a.id)}}">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close" ng-click="$ctrl.closeModal()"></button>
            </div>
```

component.js

```
function PhotoController($scope){
    var vm = this;

    vm.f =  [{
        albumName: "Name",
        imageSrc: 'app/images/bio.jpg',
        owner: "OwnerName",
        id: 1
    },
    {   albumName: "Name",
        imageSrc: 'app/images/bio.jpg',
        owner: "OwnerName",
        id: 2
    }];

vm.togglePicture = function(id) {
        $('#myModal').addClass('is-active');

    };
```

I'm trying to get imageSrc by passing id of an image as a function parameter but is not working. What should I do in my function to select correct imageSrc using id and then to display it and how my imageSrc should look like?

Was thinking something like this `<img ng-src="{{togglePicture(a.id)}}">`?

Comment: In <img ng-src="{{togglePicture(a.id)}}">  you have used function & togglePicture(a.id) is not returning image url.

Comment: seems two repeaters? , why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Selected image in funnction.

```
<div class="photo topIconsHover" ng-click="$ctrl.togglePicture(a)">
```

Then set selcted image in controller

```
vm.selectedImgsrc='';

vm.togglePicture = function(a) {
        $('#myModal').addClass('is-active');
        vm.selectedImgsrc=a.imageSrc;
    };
```

Then modify modal to view selected image

```
<p class="image is-4by3">
    <img ng-src="{{$ctrl.selectedImgsrc}}">
</p>
```